# How do I install Sublime Text 2/3?I tried but I am getting error

Tags: command-line, sublime-text

Lenovo-G50-80:~$ get -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
No command 'get' found, but there are 18 similar ones
get: command not found
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: You want `wget`

Comment: I dont know much about linux.I am new at it.I just wanted to know how to download software using command prompt.And I wanted to download sublime text editor.But I could not do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `-O` parameter separately. Try this:

```
wget -q -O - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add
```

Answer (score 0):

Examine the error that is being displayed when you execute that command. It is telling you "No command 'get' found". This is due to the fact you are trying to download that key file from the web. You want to use the wget (web get) command.

> wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo
>   apt-key add -

This install guide will help you with your install.

http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/05/30/install-sublime-text-3-ubuntu-16-04-official-way/

Comment: Actually I tried that.after pressing enter a line shows up asking for password.after typing password ,I waited for hours ,But nothing happens.just the cursor is blinking.

Comment: That sounds to me like it is asking for the root password. You need to provide that. This is normal for any type of software installs or system changes in Ubuntu.

Comment: I provided it.But after that it is blinking for hours.

Comment: Finally it said something                                                                              wget -qO - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo] password for nazmul: 
   gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: Try adding the O parameter separately. Try this:
`wget -q -O - https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`